# GTK: How is it possible to keep the popup menu open when a click event occurs on menu?

Tags: c++, menu, popup, gtk, contextmenu

I have a popup menu that has a submenu includes checkable items. I want to keep submenu open when user check/uncheck an item so that the user can do something new check/uncheck.

How is it possible to keep the popup menu open when a click event occurs on menu?

Problem is in LibreOffice and code pointer of the popup menu is here: http://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/core/vcl/unx/gtk/gtksalmenu.cxx#408

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried @theGtknerd's method in here popup doesn't reopen:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>                                                            

int show_popup(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event) {

  const gint RIGHT_CLICK = 3;
  const gint LEFT_CLICK = 1;

  if (event->type == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS) {

      GdkEventButton *bevent = (GdkEventButton *) event;

      if (bevent->button == RIGHT_CLICK || bevent->button == LEFT_CLICK) {      

          gtk_menu_popup_at_pointer(GTK_MENU(widget), event);
          }
      return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *ebox;
  GtkWidget *pmenu;
  GtkWidget *reOpenMi;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Popup menu");

  ebox = gtk_event_box_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), ebox);

  pmenu = gtk_menu_new();

  reOpenMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Minimize");
  gtk_widget_show(reOpenMi);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(pmenu), reOpenMi);

  g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(reOpenMi), "activate", 
      G_CALLBACK(show_popup), GTK_MENU_SHELL(pmenu));    

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(ebox), "button-press-event", 
      G_CALLBACK(show_popup), pmenu);  

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can always _reopen_ the popup menu depending on the widget that was clicked. Not ideal maybe, but a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply @theGtknerd I've edited my question. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I only know Python. Are all the signals working as expected? I would start printing out some feedback, and see if you can figure out what is not working.